# [[deprecated]] results in error instead of warning in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, attributes

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated) `[[deprecated("message string")]]` we should be able to use the symbol but in VS results in error instead.

For example I wan't to issue a warning for ANSI methods in UNICODE builds and vice versa:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
[[deprecated("This method does not work well in UNICODE builds")]]
#endif // UNICODE
    void f() {}
```

compiler doesn't let me compile, but standard says the attribute should allow usage but issue a warning message.

How to resolve this?, btw. my project is set to maximum conformance with the standard.

What ever the reason for VS going against the standard, is there a better way to issue a warning for above case?

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau if you run above code you'll get the same `error C4996: 'f': this function should not be used UNICODE build` I reported the problem here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/760394/compiler-bug-deprecated-attribute-results-in-error.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very much late to the party, but this cost me a couple of hours this morning.

By default, Visual Studio and the sdl (Security Development Lifecycle) compile flag treat
`[[deprecated]]` as an error. Whether or not you agree with this or not, that's how they do it.

To fix this go to `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line` and add `/sdl /w34996`

The /wX part represents the severity of the warning, and the rest is the error you want to report as a warning.

I hope this saves people some time.

Comment: As I had hoped I would save you some time... :)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get the compiler to treat [[deprecated]] as a warning by adding

> /w34996

to the compiler options, as suggested in the responses in following link

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/786502/cant-treat-deprecated-warning-as-warning-with-wx.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me without the /sdl flag too...

Answer (score 1):

> is there a better way to issue a warning for above case?

There's no other way of warning about usage of a function than deprecation attribute in standard C++ at least that I know of.

Msvc has other alternatives such as `#pragma deprecated(f)`, but those are not better.

> How to resolve this?

Assuming you haven't configured your compiler to treat warnings as errors, you could proceed with writing a bug report to the maintainers.

Comment: I have check msvc compiler conformance table and MS says it supports `[[deprecated]]` attribute since VS 2015, so it's obviously a bug or I have misconfigured something, I make a new project and do a test https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Comment: nope, it doesn't compile even with fresh project template. definitelly a bug, thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it with Visual Studio, but in my case the following helped and probably is more generic:

On that error usually warnings are treated as errors with the compiler flag `-Werror`, that is automatically set in Visual Studio. That is the reason way a class or function marked with `[[deprecated]]` results in an error. To avoid explicitly that error and output it just as a warning, the compiler flag `-Werror -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations` can be set. In CMake it would look like:

```
add_compile_options(-Werror -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations)
```